# Webdriver typing very slow in IE11 and Windows 10

Tags: selenium, webdriver, iedriverserver

While executing testcases the characters are getting typed very slow.
I am using Windows10 + Selenium 2.39 + IE 11 + IEDriverServer(64bit), tried replacing it with 32 bit also but to no avail.All security zones setting are checked and have tried all available resources online.Any solutions or shall i downgrade the OS to windows 7(as it was working fine on win7).

Comment: Upgrade to _Selenium v3.10.0_ and _IEDriverServer(64bit)/(32bit) v3.10.0_ and update the question with your observation.

Comment: @Debanjan, With Selenium3.10 and IEdriverServer 64 bit I get "CommandlineServer fOr IEdriver has stopped working"

Comment: How about _IEDriverServer(32bit) v3.10.0_ ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use IEDriverServer(32bit) to solve this issue.

Comment: tried that also there also it was typing very slow with/without Desiredcapabilities

Comment: I also used 32 bit driver, but sendkeys was still slow. Check for a registry key entry `TabProcGrowth` in the path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` and delete it and try again. It worked for me with `IEDriverServer(32bit) v3.9.0`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same slowwwww typing problem when trying to use "InPrivate" browsing with IEDriver 32-bit.  The InPrivate mode was to ensure that saved credentials wouldn't be used for a "first-time user registration/login" test scenario that included a multi-factor authentication step to send a confirmation code.

It turned out that using the "InPrivate" option with the IEDriver and the ***ForceCreateProcessApi = true*** option triggered a 64-bit process to start, and that 64-bit process then invoked the IE browser.  I'm not sure if the browser was 64bit or 32bit, but the 32-bit IEDriver was super-slow in sending keystrokes to the IE 11 browser running inside this 64-bit Windows 10 process.

The IEDriver 32-bit approach required use of the ForceCreateProcessApi option, in order to get the combination to work.
The resulting super-slow typing in tests made the overall tests unacceptably slow.

***Here's what worked for me:***

- Use the 64-bit IEDriver
- Do NOT specify the "ForceCreateProcessApi = true" option
- Add or change the registry value: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth 
  TabProcGrowth is a value under Internet Explorer\Main key. I created a DWord value for TabProcGrowth under Internet Explorer\Main, and set the value to 0.

Code for setting up the IEDriver looked like this:

```
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
ieOptions.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
ieOptions.BrowserCommandLineArguments.Insert(0,"-private");
var _driver64 = new InternetExplorerDriver($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}", ieOptions);
_driver64.Manage().Window.Maximize();
_driver64.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.mypage.com");
```

then the code for interacting was same as 32-bit code, as follows:

```
IWebElement userName = _driver64.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"username\"]"));
userName.SendKeys("MyUserID");
```

I had success using the 64-bit IEDriver from here:  https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
Look for the heading "The Internet Explorer Driver Server" and locate the 64-bit version.
The version that was posted at the time self-reports as being version 3.14.0.0.

Ultimately I wanted to use a NuGet package, and I wanted a package where the name of the exe was "IEDriverServer.exe", same as the 32-bit filename.  I wound up using this one:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebDriver.IEDriverServer.win64/3.141.0  with a GitHub location of: 
https://github.com/SeriousM/WebDriver.IEDriverServer-nuget

It is working well for me thus far.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that IEdriver 64bit was typing very slow. I tried clicking 'Enable Enhanced Protection Mode' under Internet Options~Advanced. But that did not help for the Windows 2012 64bit IIS VM that I am working on.

There was no TabProcGrowth registry key under Main.

So I followed others suggestion to use 32bit version from seleniumhq.org. But that did not solve my issue.

I then unchecked 'Enable Enhanced Protection Mode' in Internet Options. That fixed my issue.